# Closed question banner contains incorrect information about the reasons

Tags: bug, closed-questions, banners

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034067/prove-language-is-not-regular-with-pumping-lemma?noredirect=1 was recently closed, and the banner says, inaccurately:

> put on hold as off-topic by Micah, hardmath, daw, Rafflesia arnoldii, MJD

The first four of those five users did vote to put it on hold as off-topic.  But MJD did not.  MJD voted to close because the question is a duplicate of [How do we choose a good string for the pumping lemma?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681614/how-do-we-choose-a-good-string-for-the-pumping-lemma).

I wish the banner accurately described the state of affairs.

Comment: (Similar issues have been raised here before, but I couldn't find them.)

Comment: But read further: "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

    "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." – Micah, hardmath, daw, Rafflesia arnoldii" <- No MJD.

Comment: You're right, thanks.  I thought there was something like that, and looked for it, and somehow didn't see it.  I still think the banner should be rearranged to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The closure process is very democratic. The majority chosen reason takes the banner. Here are the (some?) exceptions:

1. If each reason was chosen just once, the last reason is taken.
2. If a moderator casts a vote, that vote is binding (which means, I think, that dupe-hammers also work that way).
3. If there are several off-topic reasons, they will show up with the different users who chose them.
4. If the question is migrated, no banner appears, of course. Unless the migration is rejected, in which case the question is closed as off topic.